# Apollo Server 4: context.user Remains Empty After Successful Login

Tags: node.js, typescript, apollo-server

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am working with Apollo Server 4 and facing an issue where context.user remains empty after a successful login. I've implemented a login system using JWTs and cookies, but the user field in the context does not persist across requests.

Here's the relevant part of my createContext function:

server.ts

```
import {ApolloServer} from '@apollo/server';
import {startStandaloneServer} from '@apollo/server/standalone';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import {typeDefs} from './application/graphql/typeDefs';
import {resolvers} from './application/graphql/resolvers';
import UserInterface from "./domain/interface/model/user.interface";
import jwt, {JwtPayload} from "jsonwebtoken";
import {IncomingMessage, ServerResponse} from "http";
import {User} from "./infrastructure/model/user.model";

mongoose.connect('mongodb://user-db:27017/user-service').then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
});

require('./domain/config/passport');

interface ContextType {
    req: IncomingMessage;
    res: ServerResponse;
    user?: string | null;
}

const server = new ApolloServer<ContextType>({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
});

async function findUserById(id: string): Promise<UserInterface | null> {
    try {
        console.log("Find user by id:", id);
        return await User.findById(id);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Find user by id error:", error);
        return null;
    }
}

async function createContext({ req, res }: { req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse }): Promise<ContextType> {
    let user: string | null = null;

    const token = req.headers.cookie?.split('; ')
        .find(cookie => cookie.startsWith('jwt='))
        ?.split('=')[1];

    if (token) {
        try {
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET ?? 'SECRET_KEY');
            if (typeof decoded === 'object' && decoded.id) {
                const userData = await findUserById(decoded.id);
                user = userData ? userData.id : null;
                console.log("User:", user);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("JWT Error:", error);
            res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'jwt=; HttpOnly; Path=/; Max-Age=0');
        }
    }

    return { req, res, user };
}



startStandaloneServer(server, {
    listen: { port: 4001 },
    context: createContext
}).then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

resolver.ts

```
import {User} from '../../infrastructure/model/user.model';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import jwt, {JwtPayload} from 'jsonwebtoken';
import {
    loginValidationSchema,
    signUpValidationSchema,
    updateEmailValidationSchema,
    updateLocationValidationSchema,
    updatePasswordValidationSchema,
    updateValidationSchema
} from "../../infrastructure/dataValidation/mutation.validation";
import {
    ContextType,
    QueryArgs, UpdateLocation,
    UpdateUserInput,
    UserInput
} from "../../domain/interface/mutation/utils.mutation.interface";

function updateUserFields(userId: string, updateFields: object) {
    return User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        userId,
        {...updateFields, updated: new Date().toISOString()},
        {new: true}
    );
}

function verifyAuthenticatedUser(context: ContextType) {
    if (!context.user) throw new Error('You are not authenticated!');
    return context.user;
}

export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        me: async (_: any, __: any, context: ContextType) => {
            const userId = verifyAuthenticatedUser(context);
            return User.findById(userId);
        },
    },
    Mutation: {
        signUp: async (_: any, args: { user: UserInput } , context: ContextType) => {
            const { error } = signUpValidationSchema.validate(args.user);
            if (error) throw new Error(`Validation error: ${error.details.map(x => x.message).join(', ')}`);
            const newUser = new User({
                ...args.user,
                created: new Date().toISOString(),
                updated: new Date().toISOString(),
            });
            return await newUser.save();
        },
        login: async (_: any, {username, email, password}: QueryArgs, context: ContextType) => {
            const { error } = loginValidationSchema.validate({username, email, password});
            if (error) throw new Error(`Validation error: ${error.details.map(x => x.message).join(', ')}`);
            if (!username && !email) throw new Error('Username or email is required!');
            const user = await User.findOne({$or: [{username}, {email}]});
            if (!user) throw new Error('Invalid credentials!');
            const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
            if (!isMatch) throw new Error('Invalid credentials!');

            const token = jwt.sign({id: user.id}, process.env.SECRET ?? 'SECRET_KEY', {expiresIn: '1h'});
            context.res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `jwt=${token}; HttpOnly; Path=/; Max-Age=${60 * 60}`);
            context.user = user.id;
            return token;
        },
        logout: (_: any, __: any, context : ContextType) => {
            const userId = verifyAuthenticatedUser(context);
            const token = context.req.headers.cookie?.split('=')[1];
            if (!token || !userId) throw new Error('You are not authenticated!');
            try {
                const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET ?? 'SECRET_KEY') as JwtPayload;
                if (decoded.id === userId) {
                    context.res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'jwt=; HttpOnly; Path=/; Max-Age=0');
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                throw new Error('You are not authenticated!');
            }
        },
        updateUser: async (_: any, {updateFields}: { updateFields: UpdateUserInput }, context: ContextType) => {
            const { error } = updateValidationSchema.validate(updateFields);
            if (error) throw new Error(`Validation error: ${error.details.map(x => x.message).join(', ')}`);
            const userId = verifyAuthenticatedUser(context);
            return await updateUserFields(userId, updateFields);
        },
        updatePassword: async (_: any, {password}: { password: string }, context: ContextType) => {
            const { error } = updatePasswordValidationSchema.validate({password});
            if (error) throw new Error(`Validation error: ${error.details.map(x => x.message).join(', ')}`);
            const userId = verifyAuthenticatedUser(context);
            if (!password) throw new Error('Password cannot be empty!');
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
            const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
            return await updateUserFields(userId, {password: hashedPassword});
        },
        updateLocation: async (_: any, {location}: { location: UpdateLocation }, context: ContextType) => {
            const { error } = updateLocationValidationSchema.validate({location});
            if (error) throw new Error(`Validation error: ${error.details.map(x => x.message).join(', ')}`);
            const userId = verifyAuthenticatedUser(context);
            return await updateUserFields(userId, {location: location});
        },
        updateEmail: async (_: any, {email}: { email: string }, context: ContextType) => {
            const { error } = updateEmailValidationSchema.validate({email});
            if (error) throw new Error(`Validation error: ${error.details.map(x => x.message).join(', ')}`);
            const userId = verifyAuthenticatedUser(context);
            return await updateUserFields(userId, {email: email});
        },
        deleteUser: async (_: any, __: any, context: ContextType) => {
            const userId = verifyAuthenticatedUser(context);
            return await User.findByIdAndDelete(userId);
        },
    }
};
```

The login resolver sets the JWT in a cookie, but subsequent requests do not have the user info in the context. The JWT is sent correctly, and I can see the cookie in the browser's network tab.

Could someone please help me identify where the issue might be and how to ensure that context.user is populated correctly across requests? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Implemented createContext Function: I have a createContext function that extracts and verifies the JWT token from the cookie, and then sets the user in the context based on the token's payload

Tested Cookie Persistence: The httpOnly cookie with the JWT token is sent from the server and I can see it in the browser's network tab. However, it seems not to persist for subsequent requests.

Checked Apollo Server Configuration: I've reviewed the Apollo Server configuration to ensure the context is set up correctly.

Attempted Different Browser and Privacy Settings: I've tried different browsers and adjusted privacy settings to ensure they are not blocking or restricting cookies.

Comment: (1) Is your context function getting called on every request? (2) Is a cookie being sent with every request?

Comment: my context function in my server.ts file is called on every request yes. The cookie is only sent when the user log in

Comment: Sorry, I meant is the cookie being included with every request from the *client* to the server?